# Counting the number of times a name appears next to a date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I currently have a pivotTable where each row is a date and each column is an employee. The values in the intersection are the sum of the hours worked that day. From another sheet/tab, I would like to be able to enter two dates in a cell and in the respective table, count the number of days for which the hours worked is more than 0.

Currently, I am using a COUNTIF() statement that selects a given number of rows from the hours log and ands counts the number of entires greater than zero. However, I have to scroll through and select the rows myself. I want the formula to be able to take any two days I type in, and find those days in the sheet. Does this make sense?

Here is the formula I have for reference:

```
=COUNTIF('Work Hours'!D107:D111, ">0")
```

In this case, a person's name is in column D, and the rate range I wanted are in rows 107 to 111.

[This sheet shows where I want the attendance to go. The names are blacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce1qj.png)

[This sheet shows the pivotTable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InjO7.png)

Comment: Have you considered COUNTIFS instead of COUNTIF?

Comment: @markfitzpatrick I am familiar with COUNTIFS but how do I use that with a date range? I have used it for numerical ranges before

Comment: good point - not that easy.  OK - let's go with SUM - just a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your hours are in cells **'Work Hours'!D5:D200** and your dates are in **'Work Hours'!C5:C200**. Let's say that your **start date is in D3** and your **end date is E3** (on your summary sheet).

The formula to count entries with more than zero hours between the start and end date would be:

```
=SUM(('Work Hours'!D$5:D$200>0)*('Work Hours'!$C$5:$C$200>=$D$3)*('Work Hours'!$C$5:$C$200<=$E$3))
```

This creates an array of TRUE/FALSE values that when multiplied result in 0's and 1's.  So TRUE * TRUE = 1 * 1 = 1 and TRUE * FALSE = 1 * 0 = 0. Type this into a cell `=TRUE * FALSE` and you can see for yourself. SUM then adds up all of the 1's and that's your answer.

I am not sure how this fits on your worksheet, but you get the idea.